# Disabling Chrome dev tools cursor blinking?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to disable/stop the cursor blinking behavior on the Chrome developer tools?

On Windows, there's a way that universally disables cursor blinking, through the setting `Control Panel > Keyboard > Cursor blink rate`, this actually prevents cursor blinking on Chrome.

But for some apps it doesn't work. For example, on the Chrome developer tools.
So, is there a way to stop this? for example, something like styling the dev tools CSS? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see the blinking cursor in DevTools? Is it the console?

Comment: Mainly in the console tab, and in the sources tab.

Comment: Can you record it as a video to demostrate? Feel free to open bug ticket in crbug.com and post the link here, I can follow up.